# Create SEQUENCE based dictionary from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this,

I am trying to prepare a dictionary from the list ,

the list is like this,

```
result = [{'comp_seq': 1, 'benefit_category_name': 'Standard Benefits', 
           'sale_line_id': 34353, 'benefit_name': 'TPA',  
           'insurance_category_name': 'A', 'benefit_categ_seq': 1},
          {'comp_seq': 1, 'benefit_category_name': 'Standard Benefits', 
           'sale_line_id': 34354,'benefit_name': 'TPA', 
           'insurance_category_name': 'B', 'benefit_categ_seq': 1},
          {'comp_seq': 1, 'benefit_category_name': 'Standard Benefits', 
           'sale_line_id': 34355, 'benefit_name': 'TPA',  
           'insurance_category_name': 'A', 'benefit_categ_seq': 1}, 
          {'comp_seq': 1,  'benefit_category_name': 'Standard Benefits',  
           'sale_line_id': 34356, 'insurance_category_name': 'B', 
           'benefit_categ_seq': 1}]
```

I looking for the dictionary like this,

```
{1: 
    {'Standard Benefits': 
        {1: 
            {'TPA': 
                [{'B': 
                    [{34353: [None, True, None, False]},
                     {34354: ['Aafiya', False, None, False]}, 
                     {34355: [None, True, None, False]}, 
                     {34356: ['Aafiya', False, None, False]}]}, 

                 {'A': 
                    [{34353: [None, True, None, False]},
                     {34354: ['Aafiya', False, None, False]}, 
                     {34355: [None, True, None, False]}, 
                     {34356: ['Aafiya', False, None, False]}]},
                    ]
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

But actually I get the dictionary like this after my code,

```
{1: 
    {'Standard Benefits': 
        {1: 
            {'TPA': 
                [{'B': 
                    [{34353: [None, True, None, False]},
                     {34354: ['Aafiya', False, None, False]}, 
                     {34355: [None, True, None, False]}, 
                     {34356: ['Aafiya', False, None, False]}]}, 
                 {'A': [}]},
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I wrote to prepare the dictionary,

```
cat1= []
for key, value in itertools.groupby(result, key=itemgetter('insurance_category_name')):
    cat1.append(key)
cat = list(set(cat1))
seq_d = {}
seq_sort_res = sorted(result, key=itemgetter('benefit_categ_seq'))
for seq, bc_val in itertools.groupby(seq_sort_res, key=itemgetter('benefit_categ_seq')):
    bc_d = {}
    ben_categ_sort_result = sorted(bc_val, key=itemgetter('benefit_category_name'))
    for bc, bf_val in itertools.groupby(ben_categ_sort_result, key=itemgetter('benefit_category_name')):
        bseq_d = {} 
        benefit_seq = sorted(bf_val, key=itemgetter('comp_seq'))
        for bseq, bseq_val in itertools.groupby(benefit_seq, key=itemgetter('comp_seq')):
            bf_d = {} 
            for bf in bseq_val:
                if bf.get('benefit_name') not in bf_d:
                    bf_d.update({bf.get('benefit_name'): []})
                    for c in cat:
                        if c not in bf_d[bf.get('benefit_name')]:
                           bf_d.get(bf.get('benefit_name')).append({c: []})
                content = []
                vals = ['description', 'is_checked', 'comment', 'highlight']
                for v in vals:
                    content.append(bf.get(v))
                s = {bf.get('sale_line_id'): content} 
                list(bf_d[bf.get('benefit_name')][0].values())[0].append(s)
            bseq_d.update({bseq: bf_d})
        bc_d.update({bc: bseq_d})
    seq_d.update({seq: bc_d})
```

But the dictionary is not correctly prepared. I think some problem in looping.please identify the problem in my code?

update

---

The logic behind this problem is I decided to create dictionary like firstly benefit category sequence then next to benefit category then next one is benefit sequence and benefit like this.

With in the benefit i added a list for **category 'A' and 'B'**.within the list there is a **dictionary for 'A' and 'B'**, key is sale_line_id and values are from sale_line_id,**here is 4 sale_line id** s. and corresponding values.

The inner dictionary for category 'B' is formed correctly, but the problem is the **inner dictionary if 'A' for wrong**

update2

---

the bf dictionary from for bf in bseq_val:

the bf dictionary is

```
 {'is_checked': False, 'highlight': False, 'comment': None, 
  'comp_seq': 1, 'description': 'Aafiya', 'benefit_name': 'TPA', 
  'insurance_category_name': 'B', 'benefit_categ_seq': 1,  
  'benefit_category_name': 'Standard Benefits', 'sale_line_id': 34354}
```

this type of 4 dictionaries formed in looping. 
the only major different is the **category 'A' for 2 dictionaries and 'B'** for 2 dictionaries.

Comment: Can you explain more the logic behind how should be the output dictionary prepared from the input list?

Comment: Where does "aafiya" come from? I don't see it in the input data, is it something we "just know" up front?

Comment: @JonKiparsky:"aafiya" from description, from this statement ------content.append(bf.get(v)).   bf is the dictionary that contains the 'description', 'is_checked' as key and corresponding values

Comment: Can you please include all of the relevant information in the question? This `bf` dictionary seems relevant.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: I updated with bf dictionary and content

Comment: @aslamsha22 I have spent about twenty minutes looking at your code, and I have two suggestions. First, when you have code that nests this deeply, make functions and give them names. Second, when you're tempted to build a data structure out of dictionaries and lists, make an object instead. Bonus suggestion: improve your variable names. They should immediately tell you what you need to know about the purpose of the variable, it is not enough for them to sort of make sense in retrospect. Sorry I can't be more help improving this attempt, better luck on your next go.

Comment: @JonKiparsky:Thnkas for the comment and your time and suggestion,I will improve myself with your valuable suggetion.

Comment: @aslamsha22 I strongly recommend a book by Robert Martin called Clean Code - I think this will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not clear to me. But, if I understand, you want to transform a list of dicts into a tree (or a forest if you have more than one root), following a predefined list of groups. The groups are ordered from the roots to the leaves:

```
groups = ['benefit_categ_seq', 'benefit_category_name', 'comp_seq', 'insurance_category_name', 'sale_line_id']
```

Instead of hardcoding the hierarchy, you can use the list above to build the tree:

```
def nest(L, path):
    *init_path, last_path = path # split before the last element
    root = {}
    for d in L:
        e = root # start at the root
        for g in init_path: # follow the path
            e = e.setdefault(d[g], {}) # get or create the subtree
        e[d[last_path]] = d # add the dict to the leaf

    return root
```

For every dict (that is the representation of a business object), start from the root, and follow the path:

- before the last element of the path, get or create (`setdefault`) the subtrees;
- when you reach the last element of the path, that is the id of your object, attach the object.

Here's the result:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint (nest(result, groups))
{1: {'Standard Benefits': {1: {'A': {34353: {'benefit_categ_seq': 1,
                                             'benefit_category_name': 'Standard '
                                                                      'Benefits',
                                             'benefit_name': 'TPA',
                                             'comp_seq': 1,
                                             'insurance_category_name': 'A',
                                             'sale_line_id': 34353},
                                     34355: {'benefit_categ_seq': 1,
                                             'benefit_category_name': 'Standard '
                                                                      'Benefits',
                                             'benefit_name': 'TPA',
                                             'comp_seq': 1,
                                             'insurance_category_name': 'A',
                                             'sale_line_id': 34355}},
                               'B': {34354: {'benefit_categ_seq': 1,
                                             'benefit_category_name': 'Standard '
                                                                      'Benefits',
                                             'benefit_name': 'TPA',
                                             'comp_seq': 1,
                                             'insurance_category_name': 'B',
                                             'sale_line_id': 34354},
                                     34356: {'benefit_categ_seq': 1,
                                             'benefit_category_name': 'Standard '
                                                                      'Benefits',
                                             'comp_seq': 1,
                                             'insurance_category_name': 'B',
                                             'sale_line_id': 34356}}}}}}
```

I know that's not the exact output you need, but might help.

If the `last_path` is an not an unique id, get or create the leaf (a list) and append the current dict: `e.setdefault(d[last_path], []).append(d)` instead of `e[d[last_path]] = d`.
`

Comment: :Thanks for the important information about dictionary preparation. I will definitely try this method.